# How to use global/common node_modules instead of local node_modules?

Tags: node.js, angular, global, node-modules

I want to use the **global node_modules** (`C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`) or **common node_modules** (`D:\node_modules`)  instead of local node_modules (`D:\angular\projects\project1\node_modules`).

I want to use the node_modules for various projects.

This is my project structure.

`D:\
├── node_modules (common for all projects)
│   ├── Module-N
├── projects
│   ├── project1
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── app
│   │   |    ├── Module-N (importing from common)
|
│   ├── project2
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── app
│   │   |    ├── Module-N (importing from common)
|
├── ....`

Answer (score 0):

try working with relative path like when you require you own modules for the global models

for example

assuming we want to get a module from the global node modules and the file we are working on is seats on projects/project1/src

we will do `require('../../../node_modules/my_global_model')`

Answer (score 0):

try looking into `tsconfig`s paths: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: I got the below, when start the angular application (project1) using angular cli (ng serve/build)..  `ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\Angular\Project1\node_modules`